# select first child of table in an email from outlook 2010

Tags: css, outlook-2010

I send an email to outlook 2010 client.
Here is the code:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="lorem">AAA</div>
    <div class="ipsum">BBB</div>
    <div class="dolor">CCC</div>
    <div class="lorem">This div has to be hidden</div>
    <div class="ipsum">BBB</div>
    <div class="dolor">CCC</div>
    <div class="lorem">This div has to be hidden</div>
    <div class="ipsum">BBB</div>
    <div class="dolor">CCC</div>
</div>
```

How to hide all "lorem" class except the first one ? I already tried ".content > div:first-class" but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
.content .lorem:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: The only other thing I can think of now is just try adding important - `display: none !important`.

Comment: doesn't work. it's not an issue due to display:none. If I replace display:none by color:red; I can see that the text is not in red... So it means that element is not selected

Comment: Oh.. I rememebered now for outlook you actually need to have inline styles for each element, but I guess it's not applicable in your situation. Maybe you have to find a way to exclude what you don't want visible generally before sending it. Sorry I couldn't help.